# uploadify not uploading images using php

Tags: php, file-upload, uploadify

I want to use uploadify to upload my multiple images.

**What is scenario**

I want to upload multiple images. I also want to enter the information of each uploaded image in database as well. As at `oncomplete event I want to get the ids of all newly entered ids of table

**What I have done**
my uploadify code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fileid').uploadify({ 
    'uploader'  : '<?php echo SITEURL;?>/admin/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '<?php echo SITEURL;?>/admin/action_files/area_pics_upload.php',
    'cancelImg' : '<?php echo SITEURL;?>/admin/uploadify/cancel.png',
    //'folder'    : '<?php echo SITEURL;?>/admin/uploadify/uploads',
    'auto': 'true',
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'  : 'Image Files (*.JPEG,*.JPG, *.GIF, *.PNG)',
    'multi'     : true,
    'onAllComplete': function(event, data)
     {  alert(data); }


 });
```

});

Code in area_upload_pics.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES))
{
$allowedExtensions = array("jpeg","jpg","gif","png"); 
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES);$i++)
{
    if(in_array(end(explode(".",strtolower($_FILES['fileid'][$i]['name']))),$allowedExtensions))
    {
        $file = time().'-'.$_FILES["fileid"][$i]['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileid"][$i]["tmp_name"],'../../uploaded_files/area_pics/'.$file)
        {
            //save file info in database
            $q = "INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."_files (file) values (".$file.")";
            mysql_query($q);
     $images_ids[]=mysql_insert_id();
        }
    }
}
}

echo(json_encde($images_ids);
```

**My Problem**

Images are not being uploaded. I haved checked the paths that are good. What amI doing wrong.

Comment: what's the error? and try with a file with lower size

Comment: @yes123 files are not being uploaded.

Comment: Action file is area_pics_upload.php and before the code you have posted "Code in area_upload_pics.php".I am not sure its the cause of your problem but you can try correcting this.

Comment: you should see at which line your code stops. Try echoing something inside teh various if

Comment: @AngelWorkz path is correct as I mentioned in script tag

Comment: @yes123 I have echo and even die but I think control doesn't transfer to that file as I don't see any echoed thing

Comment: Come back to us when you identify the broken if

Comment: @yes123 dude sorry I didn't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having wrong concept about uploadify. I was thinking that it hits single time to uploading resource(file doing uploading) so we have to have `$_FILES` as array. 
But the uploadify hits the uploading script as many times as you have selected the files to upload. For example you have selected 6 files to upload. Uploadify will hit your uploading script stated in `script` property of uploadify 6 times. So you don't need to use `for loop` and iterate through `$_FILES`. Just use the script as you use for single file uploading.

This is for those having same problem. :-)